# Как на сервере запросить данные из всех найденных там бд на Java оптимальней?

Tags: java

на сервере лежат бд с одинаковой схемой (порядка 100-200 штук), в каждой в определенной таблице хранится версия бд. Надо найти все бд с нужной версией.

Я нашла вариант с java spring - Hikari ( https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic ) который может на лету переключать бд, все имена бд можно узнать перед этим show schema, но будет ли это быстро для такого количества переключений? А если еще по нескольким серверам придется поискать базы? Есть ли другой путь? (может на чистой java можно лучше-быстрее реализовать)?

Comment: там же есть еще https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source может будет проще. А сделать одну мастер-базу и хранить там версии с указанием бд никак не получится?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov, спасибо посмотрю по ссылке. Общая база как раз есть и ее надо наполнять шарясь по остальным.

Comment: По вашей ссылке я так понимаю заранее надо знать список бд

Comment: Быстрее будет использовать чистый JDBC и DriverManager.getConnection(...). Дело в том, что Hikari создает пулл подключений. Например при создании datasource -> у вас будет создано сразу 10 подключений к БД. Если вам нужно выполнить простой запрос, тогда не стоит использовать Hikari или другие connection pool'ы.

Comment: @aleshka-batman добавьте ваш комментарий как ответ, он решает мою задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cамым быстрым способом подключения к базе данных в данном случае - будет использование класса `DriverManager`:

```
try (var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
     var statement = connection.createStatement();
     var resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query) {
     ...
}
```

Connection pool'ы, как правило, создают множество соединений к базе данных. Помимо множества соединений, connection pool'ы могут запускать асинхронные потоки для мониторинга соединений, сбора статистики и много другого. (Все это есть в Hikari).

Comment: Еще добавила мультипоточность, и использовать одно и то же соединение на все запросы, получилось 12 сек на 420 бд, очень хороший результат